# Retool UT read data from component

Tags: retool

Hi I am new to retool and I am trying to add unit test in retool. In my test I try to access data of a table, but somehow the data is always "null", even I can saw there has content in data in Failed log.

```
await my_search_button.setValue("Test Name");
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 6000));
assertCondition(table1.data ===  "Test Name"); 
/* When I execute this line I can see in my 
failed log that my data is

table1.data: {
"associated_company_name": [
"Test Name"
], 

*/

/* But when I try to access the associated_company_name in data like below, I will get an error message : "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'associated_company_name')" */

assertCondition(table1.data.associated_company_name ===  "Test Name");
```